# Add python27 to windows path while using python 3.3

Tags: python, windows, path

I use python 3.3.2 on windows everyday, so i added C:\Python33 to my PATH in order to be able to call "python foo.py" from console and get python 3.3.2 to execute it.

But sometimes, i also need to use python 2.7. How could i add a "python27" entry to my path, in order to call "python27 bar.py" and get python 2.7 to execute it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it using [pylauncher](http://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher):

```
C:\> py -2.7 bar.py
```

Or add at the top of bar.py:

```
#! python2.7
```

then:

```
C:\> py bar.py
```

will use Python 2.7 version.

If pylauncher is configured to handle Python scripts; you could just call:

```
C:\> bar.py
```

Or

```
C:\> bar
```

if .py is in PATHEXT

Answer (score 0):

1. Move `C:\Python27\python.exe` to `C:\Python27\python27.exe`
2. Add `C:\Python27` to your PATH.

Comment: This trick does the job, but comes with new problems as other tools like "pip" now can't find C:\Python27\python.exe

Comment: If you're working in a virtualenv (highly recommended), you can specify the python version when you create the virtualenv like this: "virtualenv -p C:\python27\python27.exe myenv". Then, when the env is activated, pip and other tools will use the environment's python (which would be 2.7), in addition to the other benefits of virtualenv.

Comment: I haven't heard of virtualenv, i'll try it. Thanks for the tip !